# Need help adding new stored property to UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I would like to add a `secondTag` to `UITableView` as a stored property.

But when I try to extend `UITableView` and use my `CustomTableView` like so:

`func tableView(_ tableView: CustomTableView , numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int`

the tableView protocols (`UITableViewDelegate`, `UITableViewDataSource`) gives me an error for not following its demands.

What are my options for adding that `secondTag` property to `UITabelView`? 
Should I override the tableView protocols? 
Should I create a custom tableView `UITableViewDataSource` that its methods accept my `CustomTableView` as the function’s parameter type?

Comment: You should still use UITableView as the type in the delegate methods. They will still work with your subclass

Comment: You first might want to ask why you need a second tag property. Maybe there's a better solution than needing two tags on a table view.

Comment: @rmaddy, The reason I needed the "second tag" property (for the `UITableView`) is for a sub tableView nested under a parent tableView. I needed an indexing solution since I only have access to the `indexPath` of the current tableView (in `tableView didSelectRowAt`) but I what to have the index of the parent view as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When implementing the protocol methods, the method signatures need to match the types defined in the protocol.  The protocol methods expect `UITableView`, so implement that function signature, and then cast to your type inside of the function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView , numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    guard let tableView = tableView as? CustomTableView else { return 0 }

    // now you can access tableView.secondTag
}
```

Comment: Did this work for you? Do you need any clarification?

Comment: Hi @vacawama, yes, it worked (thank you for that) though now I keep getting the following error, despite setting the cell identifier (under the sub tableView*): "**unable to dequeue a cell with identifier middleCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard**". (*my system has a parent tableView and a sub tableView nested under the parent's custom prototype cell)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your setup.  Do you have a second tableView inside of a the parent's tableViewCell?

Comment: Yes, I have a second tableView inside of a the parent's tableViewCell.

Comment: a second note. inside `tableView didSelectRowAt` I use `reloadData()` on both the current tableView (sub tableView) and its parent tableView, since I need both of them (sub/parent tableView) to change their height after a table cell has been touched.

Comment: This is too complicated to cover in comments and is really a new question.  Please describe your setup and your current results in a new question.

Comment: Here it is (the new question in details): <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56582143/unable-to-dequeue-a-cell-with-identifier-while-using-a-custom-uitableiview>

Comment: Hi @vacawama, If possible, could you take a look at the new question link? I've described the new setup in detail and specified the current results.

Comment: Hi @vacawama, Expected.