# Unable to dequeue a cell with identifier while using a custom UITableIView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my setup, I have 3 tableViews (nested) - tableView inside a tableView cell inside a tableVIew cell. 
My goal is to find out touch events on the “mid-level” tableView. When a mid-level tableView is touched, I would like to extend its and its parent tableView height to predetermined values.

I created a custom `UITableView` with a second tag property (“secondTag”) and inside the tableView methods, I cast tableView to CustomTableView. So, inside `tableView didSelectRowAt` I'll had two indexes - `IndexPath` and `secondTag`. The first one was the`IndexPath` of the mid-level `tableView` and the second one was the custom `UITableView` `tag` that used for the indexing of the “parent” `tableView`.

But despite setting the cell identifier properly (inside the storyboard) I got the following error: **"unable to dequeue a cell with identifier middleCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard"**.

One more note: inside `tableView didSelectRowAt` I used `reloadData()` on both the mid-level `tableView` cell and its parent `tableView` cell, since I needed both of them (sub/parent tableView cells) to change their height after a touch has occurred.
I think the double reloading may be the cause of my problems but I must reload both the parent and its nested “mid-level” `tableView` since I need both their heights to change after a touch was made.

*This question comes in to continue the following one: [Need help adding new stored property to UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56450470/need-help-adding-new-stored-property-to-uitableview)

Comment: What you have done so far?

Comment: @AtalayAsa, Just what I've written above.

Comment: Do you have a prototype cell for both the top level and mid level cells.  Are their identifiers set correctly?

Comment: @vacawama Yes, I have a prototype cell for all levels of cells (top, mid ...) and each cell has a unique identifier set correctly. Actually, the setup worked (didn't crush) before I started using the CustomTableView cast in the tableView's methods.

Comment: Could you add the code for your `cellForRowAt` and `didSelectRowAt` routines?  Do all 3 tableViews share the same delegate methods?